# Disconnecting/connecting plugs gives internal failure in compute()

Tags: c++, maya, maya-api

What's the right way to disconnect/connect plugs during MPxNode `compute()` method?

I have a modified plugin that it's plugs are already connected to some other objects transform nodes, it always gives me the internal failure error when I want to update its plugs connection during the `compute()` method. Both MDGModifier connect and disconnect fails. Why do I keep getting this error?

If this is not possible, is there a way I can update the connections before `compute()` kicks in? I've tried doing so in `setDepenedentsDirty()` but the dirtied plugs still hold the old value during that method. [Dirtied plug still has the old value during setDependentsDirty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692288/dirtied-plug-still-has-the-old-value-during-setdependentsdirty)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the connections during `compute()`? In theory, at least, they connections are static invariants for the node -- they are like the inputs and outputs of a function, and changing them on `compute()` is going to mess up the DAG graph by changing its topology and execution order.

Comment: Correct. Any suggestion where it's suited to change plugs connection outside `compute()` when one of the plugs are dirtied?

Comment: I think I'd add a separate MPXCommand to do the entire operation and keep the graph intact, or if you needed to manage the flow split that part out into a switch node of some kind separate from the compute functionality.

Comment: That's interesting. How do you make two MPXCommands work together in this scenario?

Comment: It'd have to be a user-initiated tool or a handler for an MSceneMessage.  Again, you really don't want to be dynamically changing the graph, it will be nasty for perf